# MVVM field set vs referenced event on INotifyPropertyChanged implementing classes

Tags: c#, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

If we have property which depends on another property (change to the first fires update of the second) we have two ways of doing this. We can make `Dependent` get only and call `RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameof(Dependent))`. Or we can make `Dependent` with backing field, and instead just assign this value to dependent property `DependentProperty = newValue`. Which is more MVVM way?

```
class Approach1 : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private object _primary;
    public object Primary { 
       get { return _primary; }
       set { 
           if(_primary != value) { 
             _primary = value; 
             RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameof(Dependent));
           }
     }

     public object Dependent {
         get { return computeValue(); }
     }

     private object computeValue() { ... } 
}
```

Second approach:

```
class Approach2 : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private object _primary;
    public object Primary { 
       get { return _primary; }
       set { 
           if(_primary != value) { 
             _primary = value; 
             RaiseOnPropertyChanged();
             Dependent = computeValue();
           }
     }

     private object _dependent;
     public object Dependent {
         get { return _dependent; }
         private set { if(_dependent != value) {
            Dependent = value;
            RaiseOnPropertyChanged();
         }

     }

     private object computeValue() { ... } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think approach 2 is more reasonable, because it is eaiser to chain events. Especially if chain is more complex and there are lots of start nodes.

Approach 1 has disadvantage, where You cannot encapsulate property computation inside that property, but in all properties which assign to it - but I think it is minor disadvantage, as You can encapsulate it in a function and call that function.